# Mouse H2 allele sequences

Tags: database, mhc, mouse

I've been trying to find complete sequences of mouse (*Mus musculus*) MHC H2 locus haplotypes for quite some time now with limited success. The EBI IMGT database has a [table of mouse H2 haplotypes](http://www.imgt.org/IMGTrepertoireMHC/Polymorphism/haplotypes/mouse/MHC/Mu_haplotypes.html#polymorphism), yet IMGT only provides haplotype sequences for human HLA genes via an [FTP sever](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/imgt/mhc/hla). I've found similar data for several other species at EBI's [IPD-MHC](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ipd/mhc/), but *Mus musculus* is not on the list. The [MGI](http://www.informatics.jax.org) database provides access to H2 SNPs, but I haven't found a mapping from SNP combinations to reconstruct happlotype sequences given reference genes.

Comment: Are you after amino acid or gene sequences?

Comment: @David I'm looking for nucleotide sequences: "I haven't found a mapping from SNP combinations to reconstruct happlotype sequences given reference genes". Protein sequences are readily available in the UniProt database.

Answer (score 2):

I have also hit this issue. I was interested in full length amino acid sequences for the classical class I mouse MHC alleles. I was able to find a number of them on uniprot but not all. Here is my list below. Interested if anyone knows additional sequences to extend this:

#### H-2 D

- [H-2 Db](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01899.fasta)
- [H-2 Dd](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01900.fasta)
- [H-2 Dp](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P14427.fasta)
- [H-2 Dk](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P14426.fasta)
- [H-2 Dq](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q31145.fasta)

#### H-2 K

- [H-2 Kb](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01901.fasta)
- [H-2 Kd](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01902.fasta)
- [H-2 Kk](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04223.fasta)
- [H-2 Kq](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P14428.fasta)

#### H-2 L

- [H-2 Ld](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01897.fasta)
- [H-2 Lq](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q31151.fasta)

Comment: Seems a useful answer to me, but I wonder whether the poster wanted gene or protein sequences. He didn’t say.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I've been using these UniProt protein sequences myself, but the question is about nucleotide sequences. Those are harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

MGI database may give you some help about Mouse H2 complex full length sequence.
https://www.informatics.jax.org/quicksearch/summary?queryType=exactPhrase&query=H2&submit=Quick%0D%0ASearch